# Templatizing A Member Field In A Custom Widget?

Tags: java, gwt, widget

I'm working on a custom widget I'm calling `SelectionField`, which (in short) adds functionality to `ListBox`, mainly to support our `HasDisplayText` interface. Here's a method that will explain what I mean:

```
public <T extends Enum<?> & HasDisplayText> void addItems(T [] items) {
    if (items != null && items.length > 0) {
        for (T item : items) {
            selectionField.addItem(item.getDisplayText(), item.name()); 
        }
    }
}
```

I call this method like this:

```
selectionField.addItems(TimeZone.values());
```

I'd like to have a property (with getter/setter) `enumClass` that allows the user to call `setEnumClass(TimeZone)`. I'm having trouble figuring out how this can be done while ensuring that the incoming Enum class will definitely implement `HasDisplayText`.

This works:

```
public <T extends Enum<?> & HasDisplayText> void setEnumClass(Class<T> enumClass) {
    if (enumClass != null) {
        T[] constants = enumClass.getEnumConstants();
        addItems(constants);
    }
}
```

...but now I'd like to declare a member field `this.enumClass` so it can be set to the incoming `enumClass`. Obviously `private <T extends Enum<?> & HasDisplayText> Class<T> enumClass` doesn't work. I can just declare the field as `private Class<?> enumClass`, be sure to do checks on the incoming class, and cast it for the return from the getter, but that seems like more of a workaround than the right approach.

(As a bonus, I'd also like to be able to edit this property in UiBinder or even GWT Designer if possible.)

How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is making the entire widget class generic an option for you? If so, this should work:

```
public class GenericBinderComposite<T extends Enum<?> & HasDisplayText> extends Composite {

   private static GenericBinderCompositeUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(GenericBinderCompositeUiBinder.class);
   interface GenericBinderCompositeUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, GenericBinderComposite<?>> {}   

   private T enumClass;

   public GenericBinderComposite() {
      initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
   }
   public T getEnumClass() {
      return enumClass;
   }
   public void setEnumClass(T enumClass) {
      this.enumClass = enumClass;
   }

}
```

The above implies the presence of `GenericBinderComposite.ui.xml`, of course.

Comment: Though I'm actually extending straight from ListBox `public class SelectionField<T extends Enum<?> & HasDisplayText> extends ListBox`, this is a pretty good answer.